# How to send sql statement to remote server via ssh

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I'm trying to send a sql command to a remote server:'=

**command:**

```
`mysql -u videoeditor -p12345 testing -e "UPDATE testing.video SET rtsp_url = INSERT(rtsp_url, LENGTH(rtsp_url) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(rtsp_url)) + 2, 0, '10101');"`
```

**my complete command to do it is:**

`ssh user@serverIP 'mysql -u videoeditor -p12345 testing -e "UPDATE testing.video SET rtsp_url = INSERT(rtsp_url, LENGTH(rtsp_url) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(rtsp_url)) + 2, 0, '10101');"'`

but it seems like my syntax is wrong

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/, REVERSE(rtsp_url)) + 2, 0, 10101)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Each single quote inside of SQL command should be replaced to '\''

Comment: Looked everywhere trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to escape the ' in the sql string since you're wrapping them inside of '' to use ssh.

```
ssh user@serverIP 'mysql -u videoeditor -p12345 testing -e "UPDATE testing.video SET rtsp_url = INSERT(rtsp_url, LENGTH(rtsp_url) - LOCATE(\'/\', REVERSE(rtsp_url)) + 2, 0, \'10101\');"'
```

Comment: Any clue how to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the host name. Please try the format as

```
mysql -p -u <mysql_username> -h <mysql_server_ip> -e "<update query>"
```

Make sure there are necessary permissions from the remote server to the MySQL server